# How to convert MTM coordinates to WGS84 with R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, wgs84, rgdal

I have MTM coordinates in the following format

```
df <- data.frame(xcentro = c(250605,250770,250871),ycentro = c(5186087,5185610,5186140))
```

and need them to be converted in the WGS84 format.
I expect the rgdal library to be able to do that, but I fail in finding the correct epsg

The only way out I see would be to implement the conversion formulas
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824732/how-to-convert-mtm-canada-coordinates-to-latitude-and-longitude
but I cannot believe it was not already implemented somehow in rgdal.

Comment: Do you know the MTM zone? There do exist EPSG Codes for MTM zones (i.e. EPSG:32189). So it is only a matter of finding the right zone

Comment: The geographical zone is Eastern Canada (Québec).

Comment: Most of the MTM zones cover a portion of Quebec. Here's a [url](https://epsg.org/search/by-name?sessionkey=pcpx4u94v8&searchedTerms=quebec%2B%5Bname%5D%3DMTM) that does a search for MTM zones that contain Quebec in their area of use.

Comment: Looks like this might be [EPSG:32187](http://epsg.io/32187) (NAD83 MTM Zone 7) which would correspond to points in Old Quebec City.

Comment: What would be the consequence if I used an epsg for another zone close by, would the precision sink or would that be negeligible (~1meter).

Comment: Your points would be hundreds of km off if you used another zone. You need to tell the system the correct zone in which your x,y points are expressed, otherwise the system will interpret and convert them wrongly. MTM zones are 3 longitude degrees wide, if your zone number is off by 1, then your point is off by 3 degrees of longitude.

Comment: thanks, feel free to edit an answer from your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your points might be in [EPSG:32187](http://epsg.io/32187) (NAD83 MTM Zone 7) which would correspond to points in Old Quebec City.

It is important to tell the system the correct coordinate system and zone that your points are expressed in. Let's take the MTM Zones as an example:

[image]

In each zone, the x,y coordinates repeat themselves, but 3 longitude degrees apart. Choosing a wrong zone would cause the system to locate your points in a completely different region. Your points would be hundreds of km off if you used another zone. MTM zones are 3 longitude degrees wide, so if your zone number is off by 1, then your point is off by 3 degrees of longitude, or +- 200 km.

Answer (score 0):

More technical details about how to do the conversion in R:

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

## Given a shapefile with coordinates projected onto MTM-zone 7
myFile <- "/path/to/file.shp"
data <- readOGR(myFile)

## Define the projection used for these data
proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32187") # MTM zone 7

## Define the new projection to use (WGS84 for lat-lon)
CRS.wgs84 <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") 

## Tranform to the WGS projection
data <- spTransform(data,CRS.wgs84)

## Look at it on a map
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() 
m %>% addPolygons(data=coords)
```